# WinAPI ComboBox shows no dropdown list

Tags: winapi, combobox, listbox

How is that a ComboBox contorl shows no dropdown list when I press its arrow button? To be precise, it "attempts" to show something but it looks like it had not enough space on the screen so that just a thin line is shown (like it was a "listbox with zero items"). When I use the up and down arrows, I can traverse through available options in the ComboBox. This picture demonstrates (note the black line below the ComboBox that has just appeared as a response to my attempt to show the dropdown list), http://nestorovic.hyperlink.cz/comboBoxProblem.PNG .
May it be that there's a bounding rectangle around the ComboBox that the listbox attempts to fit in? How can such rectangle be increased? Thanks for a reply!

Comment: The clipping area of a Combo Box can be set through the height parameter in a resource script. If the Combo Box is created dynamically, it can be set through API's like [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. I'm currently using VS Express (which lacks the resource editor) in conjunction with legacy VS6 Pro (whose resource editor lacks the height parameter modification). Anyway, I'll keep your hint in mind until I've migrated to a newer version of VS :-)

Comment: You can manually edit the .rc file. See [COMBOBOX control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380889.aspx) for documentation on the COMBOBOX definition.

Comment: P.S.: In Visual Studio 6 you can change the height of a combobox in the resource editor by clicking on the dropdown button first. This will show a frame encompassing the entire control, and allows you to resize it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hidden under the arrow button, this almost looks like an "easter egg" rather than intended behavior for developers! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem with combobox. for me solution was simple. You just need to make button height higher. When i made button height 25 there was just black thin line. But when i made height 200 then all my list appeared on button push.

```
        HWND hwndChannelList = CreateWindow(
        L"COMBOBOX",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
        L"",      // Button text 
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | BS_DEFSPLITBUTTON | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VSCROLL,  // Styles WS_VSCROLL | BS_DEFSPLITBUTTON WS_DISABLED | 
        10,         // x position 
        80,         // y position 
        100,        // Button width
        200,        // Button height
        hWnd,     // Parent window
        (HMENU)IDC_CHANNEL_COUT_BUTTON,       //menu.
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it! There's indeed a bounding rectangle which I had to increase using the GetClientRect and SetWindowPos functions, http://nestorovic.hyperlink.cz/comboBoxSolved.PNG .

Comment: Bonus reading: [Why does the size of a combo box include the size of the drop-down?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/10/548537.aspx)